# "Invalid array passed" when parsing JSON

Tags: json, powershell, powershell-3.0

I have this file which I want to read with PowerShell:

```
var myMap =
[
  {
    "name": "JSON Example",
    "attr": "Another attribute"
  }
]
```

My PowerShell v3 Code:

```
$str = Get-Content $file | Select -Skip 1;
$str | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

But I'm always getting this error:

```
ConvertFrom-Json : Invalid array passed in, ']' expected. (1): [
At S:\ome\Path\script.ps1:60 char:8
+ $str | ConvertFrom-Json;
+        ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [ConvertFrom-Json], ArgumentException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.ArgumentException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ConvertFromJsonCommand
```

If I copy and paste the JSON code manually into the code, everything is working fine:

```
'[
  {
    "name": "JSON Example",
    "attr": "Another attribute"
  }
]' | ConvertFrom-Json;
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try to pipe to `Out-String` before piping to `ConvertFrom-Json`:

```
Get-Content $file | Select -Skip 1 | Out-String | ConvertFrom-Json
```

In your working example the JSON code is a string while the non-working example returns a collection of lines. Piping to `Out-String` converts the collection to a single string, which is what the InputObject parameter accept.

Comment: It works now! Thanks for the explanation! I'll accept your answer in 4 minutes.

Comment: Thank you very much, such a great explanation

Comment: **News in 2020:** [`ConvertFrom-Json` in PowerShell 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/previous-versions/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/ConvertFrom-Json?view=powershell-5.0) now also supports arrays and multiple things piped into it, e.g. `(@("{", '"a":9}') | ConvertFrom-Json).a` works! Hence, `Out-String` is not necessary anymore.

Comment: Amazon EC2s come equipped with Powershell 4.0 and a lower version of Amazon CLI. So I ran into this same issue in the EC2 environment but not on the local machine, thanks for the workaround! You'd think they'd at least keep the CLI up to date...

Answer (score 10):

Alternatively you can use `Get-Content -Raw` which will retrieve the JSON as a single string.

See this post for more info: http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/04/23/json-is-the-new-xml.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `var myMap =` isn't json, it's javascript.  Delete the first line and it will be fine.

EDIT:

Oh, you are skipping the first line.  It may be that there's a carriage return missing in the last line of the file, and Powershell 3 is more sensitive to it.  It works fine in Powershell 5.1 even without a carriage return at the end.

Comment: Thanks for bringing up the version, that led me to looking up the docs. Indeed, `ConvertFrom-Json` in PS 5 is more relaxing wrt. its input parameters. I [commented that under the accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12140546/invalid-array-passed-when-parsing-json/59652279#comment105478520_12140654). I think that way it's most visible. I think you can safely delete this answer then to declutter the answer list a bit :)

Answer (score -1):

another answer that also works:  use `GC -raw <FILE>` which will pass in as string